# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: cannot focus element using emulator browser

Tags: java, selenium, android-emulator, focus, appium-android

I am able to click that username field but not able to pass the values in that field. Facing the below error.

```
driver.get("xxxx");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("xxxx")));
username.click();
username.sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
```

Error I received -

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> Original error: unknown error: cannot focus element   (Session info:
> chrome=69.0.3497.100)

Comment: Provide the html code of the element

Answer (score 0):

You can use click(), clear() and sendkeys() combination, it worked for me :

`username.click();`
`username.clear();`
`username.sendkeys("xxxx")`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: cannot focus element (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
```

...implies that the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) was unable to **focus** on the desired element.

To invoke `sendKeys()` instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `id`:

  ```
  WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("xxxx")));
  username.click();
  username.clear();
  username.sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#xxxx")));
  username.click();
  username.clear();
  username.sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='xxxx']")));
  username.click();
  username.clear();
  username.sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
  ```

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u271](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v87.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 87.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v87.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt)).
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.